# Android parse xml referenced by string

Tags: android

Is it possible to parse an xml file located in assets by referencing the filename as a string from res/values?

```
 Document doc = db.parse(assetManager.open("questions.xml"));
```

and instead of questions.xml something like @string/questions.xml?  I am having difficulty getting this to work.

Comment: [Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

Comment: Why you wanna do that? If you have a list of questions so use it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: I mean, i really just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: Yes, you can! Response below for @arcastro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with this code:

```
Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
String filename = res.getString(R.string.questions);
Document doc = db.parse(assetManager.open(filename));
```

Or in one simple line:

```
Document doc = db.parse(assetManager.open(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.questions));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Arcastro YES thanks this is exactly what I've been working with, the only thing is getApplicationContext errors to cannot resolve method... via the single line example

Comment: If you are not calling the method inside an activity, you'll need to pass the current Context as a parameter to be able to call getResources().

Comment: Alright what I ended up doing here is

Document doc = db.parse(assetManager.open(Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.FileName)));

but for some reason intellij cannot find a value for "filename"

Comment: check if FileName is a valid entry in your strings.xml file